# Results of comparing integers in C

Tags: c

If `x` and `y` are both `int`, will `x-y < 0` always return the same result as `x < y`?

Comment: Not if the result of `x-y` is out of range of valid `int` values.

Comment: so? what is your question. shouldn't it return the same value?

Comment: @vaibhav no because if x-y is undefined, the result will be machine dependent I guess?

Comment: @teaLeef Signed overflow is undefined behavior, not implementation-defined behavior. My answer provides a hint what this might mean: the compiler is free to rewrite x-y<0 as x<y if it wants, and it may well do this if you're asking for an optimized build.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. If `x-y` causes overflow or underflow, behavior is undefined (because int is a signed type).

For example `INT_MIN - 1 < 0` is undefined behavior, whereas `INT_MIN < 1` is defined (and true).

When there's no overflow, then the two expressions, `x-y < 0` and `x < y` are the same.

Because compiled code may do whatever it likes when there's undefined behavior, the C compiler is allowed to rewrite `x-y < 0` as `x < y` if it wishes. This isn't true if `x` and `y` are unsigned types, where overflow is well-defined, and `x-y < 0` and `x < y` are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

As @sgar91 said, No.

For example:

`X=0x80000000 //which is IntMin
 Y=1
 x-y < 0 // will be false as x-y = 0x7FFFFFFF = +Maxint`
but

`x < y //will be true`

Comment: `x-y < 0` is undefined behavior in the conditions that you have set for a typical 32-bit platform. Undefined behavior is undefined; behaving as if `x - y` was defined and evaluated to `INT_MAX` is only one of the possibilities for this code's (mis)behavior.